# Using speedtest-cli within a Python3 script to measure internet speed - getting error message 'No module named speedtest'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, speed-test

My vacation home loses the internet connection from time to time which means I cannot access that locations' home network remotely. I am using a wireless Bell service as my ISP. When I am at the vacation home, I have a program within my home automation system to reboot the Bell PoE device and the Modem. This generally always resets the network.

I am trying to use the Github project Python script **speedtest-cli** to measure the download speed at my vacation home. I am trying to write my own Python script, on a Raspberry Pi (Buster), to periodically measure the download speed of the internet. My plan is to then send a variable, with the speed, to my home automation system that will trigger a reset of the internet if the speed is too low.

I downloaded the latest script from Github  using the code

```
wget -O speedtest-cli https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py
```

Then I made the file executable with

```
chmod +x speedtest-cli
```

When I run the command *speedtest-cli*, at the Raspeberry Pi's command line, the script works as expected and I see the download speed.

However, when I try to incorporate the code into a python script I get the error 'No module named 'speedtest'

The simple code that yields this message is

```
import speedtest
```

I am running the simple script above from the /home/pi/ directory and the executable 'speedtest-cli' is also in that directory

(I know that there are numerous comments that this 'speedtest' project isn't providing accurate results, however from my testing it has been consistently yielding results that are sufficient for my purposes)

Any thought on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

For using `speedtest-cli` via a python script, would require you to install speedtest-cli on your local machine.

```
git clone https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli.git
cd speedtest-cli
python setup.py install
```

After that you can use `import speedtest`

Comment: You should have recommended virtual environment here

Comment: Jishan... I did install speedtest-cli on my Raspberry pi! I believe that what you are suggesting is simply an alternative manner in which to install it.

Comment: Marcin... I  don't understand your comment... how does a virtual environment have anything to do with my issue?

Comment: @Gary Don't you have problem running the python script with import speetest?

Comment: @JishanShaikh - Yes 'import speedtest' is not working... but why do you think that installing speedtest.cli in your manner will make it work?

Comment: @Gary Don't we all have to install the package (in any way) before using it in Python?